# Password Protect a Directory on server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My script is working perfectly on localhost but on server while logging in with username and password nothing happens .

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile    /.htpasswd.txt
require valid-user
```

Comment: Remove all those random spaces between `AuthUserFile` and your `.htpasswd` location. Require generally has a capital R too, although that shouldn't affect it.

Comment: In fact, why is your file name `.htpasswd.txt` it should just be `.htpasswd`.

Comment: changed the file name but same result

Comment: So your `.htpasswd` file is now saved correctly? It's not a `.txt` file anymore?

Comment: yes but  while loging with credentials same screen appears every time

Comment: OK, so the login screen pops up. But the credentials to log in do nothing?

Comment: Here is a last error log:   2016-07-14T12:06:34+00:00 INFO 109.65.119.195 joomlafailure Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an absolute URL to your `AuthUserFile`? It must have been created with `htpasswd` binary to avoid mistakes.

Do you have any error somewhere? Did you check you apache error file?

Comment: yes, i have written path  DOCUMENT_ROOT path after displaying phpinfo()

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If you have an error 500, you shoud check your error log (regarding to your server, it may be in the /var/log/apache2/ directory) and post here the last lines.

Comment: You may have no error displayed on screen regarding to the server configuration. Check the real error log.

Comment: Check your Apache server configuration. If you use default settings on Debian, it may be in /var/log/apache2/error.log but I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

AuthName "directory_name" should be the name of directory which is to be protected .And AuthUserFile path should be enclosed within inverted commas